# Union type not accepted by compatible overloads in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

There is the `Date` object, which can be instantiated with both a `number` or a `string`:

```
new Date("...");
new Date(123456);
```

Even though both types are supported, the union type `string|number` is not:

```
if (typeof value === "string" || typeof value === "number") {
    object = new Date(value); // Error.
}
```

> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

What's the reasoning behind this? I know I could make an `if ... else` chain, but I don't see the point. If the type of a value is one of two types, and both of those types are accepted, why can't I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making union types work with multiple overloads wasn't something that the TypeScript team thought was worth implementing ([See here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1805)). They figured that people should instead "never write a series of overloads which have an equivalent representation in union types", but currently that's not what `DateConstructor` does in *lib.d.ts*:

```
interface DateConstructor {
    new (): Date;
    new (value: number): Date;
    new (value: string): Date;
    // ... etc...
}
```

You can do an assertion to one of the types to make this work:

```
if (typeof value === "string" || typeof value === "number") {
    object = new Date(value as string);
}
```

Or create a new signature with a union type for `DateConstructor`:

```
interface DateConstructor {
    new (value: number | string): Date;
}
```

Which is actually what they should do in `lib.d.ts`...

Comment: The side effect of this otherwise well-worded answer is that it opens a new perspective for when it's time to decide whether it's multiple overload signatures or union types that provide a more robust usability experience.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you need to use the `instanceof` operator, but I'm not 100% sure on this. Secondly, because your checking for both types in one condition, the value within that code block is still considered the union type `number|string`. If you take a look at the `DateConstructor` interface in [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L792), there is no overload that takes that union type, there is an overload that takes a string and an overload that takes a number. So you will have to test each type individually.